# Regex for extracing multiple email addresses in PHP

Tags: php, regex, email-address

I'm receiving content such as:

```
"Jane Doe" <jane@doe.com>, "John Doe" <john@doe.com>
```

And I would like to extract the email addresses:

```
jane@doe.com, john@doe.com
```

Currently I have a regex like this:

```
/<(.*)>/
```

Which gets everything in between brackets, but it also gets things like:

```
jane@doe.com>, "John Doe" <john@doe.com
```

When I used an @ sign in the middle, it also didn't work quite right:

```
/<(.*)@(.*)>/
```

I could `explode()` based on the comma, but I'm thinking there ought to be a way for `preg_match()` to give me what I want. What am I missing in my regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regexp is too [greedy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#greedy). Use `/<(.*?)>/` instead, or better even something like

```
/<([^<>]+@[^<>]+)>/
```

Answer (score 3):

I use this for matching emails, I know there are other expressions out there in the wild that may catch more email address but I find this one quick to type and so far suits all my needs, feel free to give it a try:

```
/\w+[\.\w]+@\w+[\.\w]+/
```

You may want to use this with preg_match_all to capture all the addresses

for example:

```
$string = '"Jane Doe" <jane@doe.com>, "John Doe" <john@doe.com>';
preg_match_all('/\w+[\.\w]+@\w+[\.\w]+/', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to match everything except the final delimeter:

```
/<([^>]*)>/
```

Answer (score 0):

You are including too much with the dot. Try this:

```
/<([^>]*)>/
```